# Aligning HTML buttons to the right of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way for me to display **Get Maneuver** button  to the right side of **Retrieve of json file** so that users do not have to keep scrolling down, and the **Get Arrows** to the right side of **Get Maneuver**, but the result of `getArrows()` to be below **Get Arrows**.

Something like this:

[image: This is what i am trying to achieve]

```js
function getManeuver() {
  var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + document.getElementById('origin-input').value + "&destination=" + document.getElementById('destination-input').value + "&key=?";
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
      drawTable(data);

    }
  });

  function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.routes[0].legs[0].steps.length; i++) {
      drawRow(data.routes[0].legs[0].steps[i]);
    }

  }

  function drawRow(steps) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row);

    row.append($("<td>" + steps.maneuver + "</td>"));
  }

}

function getArrows() {
  $('#personDataTable td').each(function(idx, element) {
    var text = $(element).text();
    $('#Arrows').append(text + ' , ');

  });
}

function ChangetoArrows() {
  var str = document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(/undefined|turn-right|turn-slight-left|turn-slight-right|turn-left/gi, function ChangetoArrows(x) {

    if (x == 'undefined') {
      return x = '&uarr;';
    }
    if (x == 'turn-right') {
      return x = '&rarr;';
    }
    if (x == 'turn-slight-right') {
      return x = '&rarr;';
    }
    if (x == 'turn-left') {
      return x = '&larr;';
    }
    if (x == 'turn-slight-left') {
      return x = '&larr;';
    } else {
      return x;
    } //must need
  });

  document.getElementById("Arrows").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button3 {
  background-color: Blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button4 {
  background-color: Yellow;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Retrieve the Json File</button>
<p><a id="demo">Json</a></p>

<button class="button2" onclick="getManeuver()">Get Maneuver</button>
<table id="personDataTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Maneuver</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<button class="button3" onclick="getArrows()">Get Arrows</button>
<p id="Arrows"></p>

<button class="button4" onclick="ChangetoArrows()">ChangetoArrows</button>
```

Comment: As your methods reference their target explicitly you can lay out the page however you want.  I couldn't count the number of ways this could be done.

Comment: @CarlBinalla i have added the draft of roughly the positions. thank you

Comment: @JonP may you roughly explain how can i do it please?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap the "column" sections in divs and give them some CSS rules (see **.col** CSS selector)

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button3 {
  background-color: Blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button4 {
  background-color: Yellow;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Retrieve the Json File</button>
  <p><a id="demo">Json</a></p>
</div>    

<div class="col">
  <button class="button2" onclick="getManeuver()">Get Maneuver</button>
  <table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Maneuver</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <button class="button3" onclick="getArrows()">Get Arrows</button>
  <p id="Arrows"></p>

  <button class="button4" onclick="ChangetoArrows()">ChangetoArrows</button>
</div>
```